# Split String and Include Delimiter in Lua

Tags: string, split, lua

I searched on Google and on Stack Overflow and didn't find answer for this question. Looking at the documentation I didn't find how to do this because every function that allows splits excludes the delimiter.

**EDIT**

```
for i, word in pairs(split(text, "<(.-)>")) do
    print(word)
end

function split(string, delimiter) -- Got this function from https://helloacm.com/split-a-string-in-lua/
    result = {};

    for match in (string..delimiter):gmatch("(.-)"..delimiter) do
        table.insert(result, match);
    end

    return result;
end
```

This code replaces the parts in the format "<(.-)>"

Example:

```
Input: "Hello<a>World</a>!"

Expected Output: {"Hello", "<a>", "World", "</a>", "!"}

Real Output: {"Hello", "World", "!"}
```

Comment: Maybe try `string.gmatch` instead.

Comment: string.gmatch excludes the delimiter

Comment: `string.gmatch` includes whatever you tell it to include: `for v in ("a, b, c, d"):gmatch("(%w+,?)") do print(v) end`.

Comment: Show an example input and the expected output.

Comment: Updated the question with an example and the code I am using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = "Hello<a>World</a>!"
for a in s:gsub('%b<>','\0%0\0'):gmatch'%Z+' do
  print(a)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is related to HTML tags or similar.

One quick-n-dirty possibility I can think of that should cover your specific use case is this:

```
s = 'Hello<a>World</a>!'

function split(s)
  local ans = {}
  for a,b in (s..'<>'):gmatch '(.-)(%b<>)' do
    ans[#ans+1] = a
    ans[#ans+1] = b
  end
  ans[#ans] = nil
  return ans
end

for _,v in ipairs(split(s)) do
  print(v)
end
```