# Split String on delimiter and spaces in Lua

Tags: string, split, lua, delimiter

## The Problem

I am trying to syntax highlight some Lua source code, therefore I am trying to split a string of code into a table of operators, space characters and variable names.

The trouble is: I have a table of multiple separators and I want to split the string on these separators, but also keep an entry of the separators and all connected space characters:

Example:

```
"v1 *=3"
```

becomes

```
{'v1', ' ', '*=', '3'}
```

This question is awfully similair to
[Split String and Include Delimiter in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734625/split-string-and-include-delimiter-in-lua)
and
[How do I split a string with multiple separators in lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641129/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-lua)

My question however differs in that i want to keep an entry of all the separators beside each other in one entry and I can't seem to create the right pattern.

### What I have tried:

```
local delim = {",", ".", "(", ")", "=", "*"}
local s = "local variable1 *=get_something(5) if 5 == 4 then"
local p = "[^"..table.concat(delim).."%s]+"

for a in s:gsub(p, '\0%0\')gmatch'%Z+' do
    print(a)
end
```

Actual results:

```
{'local', ' ', 'variable1', ' *=', 'get_something', '(', '5', ') ', 'if', ' ', '5', ' == ', '4', ' ', 'then'}
```

Expected results:

```
{'local', ' ', 'variable1', ' ', '*=', 'get_something', '(', '5', ')', ' ', 'if', ' ', '5', ' ', '==', ' ', '4', ' ', 'then'}
```

Its a small difference, look for where the spaces are, all connected spaces should be in their own entry.

Comment: `*=` is not valid in Lua.

Comment: @lhf Yes, that is true, totally forgot. I however like to group the delimeters(and in this case operators) in one entry, so the syntax highligher can determine if it is valid and highlight it accordingly.

Comment: Can you use libraries? If so, you might want to consider using LPEG for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time i came to a solution, just posting it here if anyone should be interested.

```
local delim = {",", ".", "(", ")", "=", "*"}
local s = "local variable1 *=get_something(5) if 5 == 4 then"
local p = "[^"..table.concat(delim).."]+"

-- Split strings on the delimeters, but keep them as own entry
for a in s:gsub(p, '\0%0\')gmatch'%Z+' do

    -- Split strings on the spaces, but keep them as own entry
    for a2 in a:gsub("%s+", '\0%0\')gmatch'%Z+' do
        print(a2)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** The following seems to work for everything EXCEPT the `*=`. Still working on that, but here's the code for most everything else:

```
local delim = {"*=",",", ".", "(", ")", "=", " "}
local str = "local variable1 *=get_something(5) if 5 == 4 then"

local results = {}
local toutput = ""

function makeTable(str)
    for _,v in ipairs(delim) do
        str = str:gsub("([%"..v.."]+)", "`%1`")
    end
    for item in str:gmatch("[^`]+") do table.insert(results, item) end

    for _,v in ipairs(results) do
      toutput = toutput .. "'" .. v .. "',"
    end

    print("[" .. toutput .. "]")
end

makeTable(str)
```

It returns:

```
['local',' ','variable1',' ','*','=','get_something','(','5',')',' ','if',' ','5',' ','==',' ','4',' ','then',]
```

Hopefully this gets you one step closer.

Comment: I tried executing your code and got the results
    {'local ', 'variable1 ', '*=', 'get_something(', '5)', ' ', 'if ', '5 ', '=', '=', ' ', '4 ', 'then'}
This is sadly not what i want, since i want the space characters to take up an entry by themselves and the two equal signs should be in the same entry also the '5)' entry should be two entries '5' and ')'.

Comment: The spaces do have their own element, but yeah, I realized that the two `=` signs were not together, nor was the `*=`. This is the output I get: `['local',' ','variable1',' ','*','=','get_something','(','5',')',' ','if',' ','5',' ','=','=',' ','4',' ','then']`

Comment: curious I am actually getting an error in gsub using Lua 5.3

Comment: Nothing easily trackable, "invalid use of '%' in replacement string" in string_gsub. Don't think it is worth investigating since I can get it to work in Lua 5.1, and then i get the same result as you. But if it works in 5.1 I can try look into it

Comment: Updated code for better results. Of course, this code will do `((` as a single entry, so if that's not what you want, then we'll have to modify it again.

Comment: checked the new code, compiles nicely now, and its close, but yes, like you said *= still doesn't work. Please note that it should work for any number of seperators like [' ', ')===*', 'hi']. Atm I don't have time to look into you code and check if I can make it work

Comment: It does work for any number of separators in a row (e.g. `===`). Still no idea why it doesn't work for `*=`. I even tried subbing it out to `STAREQ` to later sub it back in, but that failed, too.